# Webdriver - Page Object model using page factory, web page withh too many links - Best Practice

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, pageobjects

Webdriver - In page Object model using page factory, i have around 25 links in a page. Should i create a variable for each of these links or is there a better way to handle this.

Comment: Id create a map of all the links that way you have one object you can pass around and get the elements from.  Map<String, WebElement> links = new Hashmap<Sting, WebElement>(); where string is a unique name for the link and the WebElement is the dom element.

Answer (score 0):

Since you'are already using [POM](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/), it'll take you little more just to create and use the approach already suggested in the comment from **bcar**. I don't know your design details and how you intend to use those links, but you can try with this simple code snippet:

```
   public class LoginPage extends BasePage{
   private Map<String, WebElement> pageLinks;

   public LoginPage(Map<String, WebElement> pageLinks){
   this.pageLinks = pageLinks;
   } 

   public Map<String, WebElement> getPageLinks(){
      return pageLinks;
   }
   }
```